# CUDA version of fastNlMeansDenoising not matching CPU version?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the following code

```
#include <cmath>
#include <omp.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/photo.hpp>
#include <opencv2/photo/cuda.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cudev/ptr2d/gpumat.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string str0 = "lenna";
    cv::Mat BW0mat = imread(str0 + ".bmp", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    cv::Mat NLMmat0;
    cv::fastNlMeansDenoising(BW0mat, NLMmat0, 11, 13, 33);

    cuda::GpuMat imageGPU;
    cuda::GpuMat reslutGPU;
    Mat NLMgpu;
    imageGPU.upload(BW0mat);
    cuda::fastNlMeansDenoising(imageGPU, reslutGPU, 11, 33, 13);
    reslutGPU.download(NLMgpu);

    NLMmat0.convertTo(NLMmat0, CV_64FC1, 1.0 / 255.0);
    NLMgpu.convertTo(NLMgpu, CV_64FC1, 1.0 / 255.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < NLMmat0.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NLMmat0.cols; j++) {
            if (NLMmat0.at<double>(i, j) != NLMgpu.at<double>(i, j))
            {
                std::cout << "i :" << i << ", j: " << j << ", cpu: " << NLMmat0.at<double>(i, j) << ", gpu: " << NLMgpu.at<double>(i, j) << "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The last loop outputs differences in the values between the CPU and GPU version of fastNlMeansDenoising. Why are these values not identical?

Comment: While ```cout``` , change ```( i , j )``` to ```( j , i )```

Comment: why would that help? I tried it and it still showed differences between the CPU and GPU versions